# CKEditor, 'enhancedcolorbuttton' plugin causing load issues

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Okay, so I did a custom build (`build-config.js` can be posted on request..), and included the plugin 'enhancedcolorbutton'. Downloaded CKEditor as a minified, ready-for-production package. (Not sources.)

When loading CKEditor onto the page, it's trying to run back and grab `plugins/enhancedcolorbutton/plugin.js`. This is returning a 404, because there is no `plugin.js` in the plugin folder on the minimized download. (The only file present is `css\content.css`.)

If I go and download the plugin manually, and copy it's contents to the ckeditor install folder (note that the downloaded plugin has other folders, too - icons and lang), I get the following errors:

`The resource name "enhancedcolorbutton" is already registered.` and
`TypeError: g is null`

So, is something wrong on their build script (guessing..) and is there a way to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at  https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/enhancedcolorbuttton. This plugin is some third-party add-on which was created for CKEditor 4.5.8 so we don't even know if it still works with 4.8.0 (author should check it against every new editor release).

Please download the 4.8.0 build and then add this plugin manually. While trying to run the editor, please see what gets returned in console. Please also check comment under the plugin - one person says there is an error `ttt` instead of `tt` so some renaming of might be needed (perhaps even inside the source files).

Comment: Okay - guessing it's not compatible with 4.8. After installing it, CKeditor reported a missing 'panelbutton' plugin. (A requirement not properly defined in the plugin?) Install that, and toolbar buttons appear - but clicking on them performs no action, and no errors listed.

Comment: Interestingly, also - in the Custom Build screen, the 'Select Your Plugins' - the 'Last Updated date is not always accurate. (The 'Panel Button' plugin reported last updated at 2013-09-10. But if you go to view the plugin's details, it lists "13 Dec 2017".)

Comment: Hi, I have tried the plugin and it was possible to install it in 4.8.0. This plugin requires two plugins https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/panelbutton and https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/floatpanel. These plugins are available in full preset by default but you need to add them to other presets either manually or through the builder. The `enhancedcolorbutton`  plugin needs to be installed manually because its name is `enhancedcolorbutton` while the folder name is `enhancedcolorbuttton`. You need to rename the folder and then drop it into CKEditor `plugins` folder.

Comment: Don't forget to add the plugin with `extraPlugins` setting and remove `colorbutton` plugin if you use full preset.

Comment: One more note - I'm using full preset by default so didn't have much problems with this plugin but it is possible that both `floatpanel` and `panelbutton` may require additional plugins if you are using editor with minimum number of plugins.